# In pandas find row per group which is smallest value greater than value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A':
            [
                'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1',
                'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2',
                'C3', 'C3', 'C3', 'C3'
            ],
        'B':
            [
                1, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7, 0
            ]
    }
)


Out[40]: 
     A  B
0   C1  1
1   C1  4
2   C1  8
3   C1  9
4   C2  1
5   C2  3
6   C2  8
7   C2  9
8   C3  1
9   C3  4
10  C3  7
11  C3  0
```

for each group in A, I want to find the row with the smallest value greater than 5

My resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
     A  B
2   C1  8
6   C2  8
10  C3  7
```

I have tried this but this does not give me the whole row

```
df[df.B >= 4].groupby('A')['B'].min()
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `idxmin` instead of `min` to extract the index, then use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df[df.B > 5].groupby('A')['B'].idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
     A  B
2   C1  8
6   C2  8
10  C3  7
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `sort_values` followed by `drop_duplicates`:

```
df[df.B > 5].sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A')
```

Output:

```
     A  B
10  C3  7
2   C1  8
6   C2  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: Filter `B` greater than five. `Groupby` `A` and find `B`'s `min` value in each group.

```
 df[df.B.gt(5)].groupby('A')['B'].min().reset_index()



  A  B
0  C1  8
1  C2  8
2  C3  7
```